# c# take only half of the byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

Question is simple, i get the first half of the byte array like this:

```
myArray.Take(128).ToArray();
```

So now how would i get the rest of the array without the first 128 bytes. Is there something similar to `Take()` or i just have to copy them to a new array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx):

```
myArray.Skip(128).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thnx, exactly what i was looking for.